# file_get_contents('php://input'); is NULL in react axios POST request to PHP curl , but the front end receives the data

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I am making an axios POST request to a PHP curl backend. I send the body as JSON and I receive a correct and usable response , but the $request_body, $data in PHP are null!! How is that possible? I have been struggling for days with this one ... any help would be awesome!

1. axios request :

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getWeather = async () => {
      try {
              const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost/eliMullan/project1/backend/src/getWikipedia.php",
          {
            selectedCountryName: selectedCountry.properties.name.replace(/\s/g,'%20'),
            GEONAMES_USER: process.env.REACT_APP_GEONAMES_USER,
            withCredentials: true
          }
        );
        const wikiData = response.data.data;
        setWikiData(wikiData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getWeather();
  }, [selectedCountry]);
```

2. php

```
    <?php
    // Get country general info 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");

    // remove for production
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);


    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    var_dump($request_body);
    $data = json_decode($request_body, true);
    $selectedCountryName = $data["selectedCountryName"];
    $geonamesUser = $data['GEONAMES_USER'];

    $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON?q=' . $selectedCountryName. '&maxRows=20&username=' . $geonamesUser;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result, true);

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode["geonames"]; 
    

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);
```

3. console.log(response) at the front end
   [image]

4. PHP server output

```
    string(0) ""
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\eliMullan\project1\backend\src\getWikipedia.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\eliMullan\project1\backend\src\getWikipedia.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "geonames" in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\eliMullan\project1\backend\src\getWikipedia.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
{"status":{"code":"200","name":"ok","description":"success","returnedIn":"89 ms"},"data":null}
```

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: I'd first try to determine if the problem is on the sending or the receiving end. You can use the browser developer tools (in particular, the "Network" tab) to determine if request is POST and payload is JSON. Proceed from there.

Comment: @aynber I get NILL for both $_POST and $_REQUEST

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I believe point 3. the console log "data" shows the body is sent as JSON . Also, the data must be sent to PHP since the API response is actually received by the front end. and used in the app without issues.  I am not sure exactly where to look into the Network tab but I will definitely give it a try . Thank you for your comment!

Comment: In the Network tool (you need to have the dev tools open before you run the code), run your code, then find the request to getWikipedia.php, click on it, and in the area which opens up, you can see the Payload section to see what was sent, and the Response section to see precisely what was received back again.

Comment: `PHP server output`...where are you seeing that output? It's not clear. Is that also in the Console when you log `response.data.data`, or somewhere else? And it's unclear what command the console screenshot you've provided is the result of?

Comment: @ADyson  Thanks for that man , I'm very grateful for the Network tool explanation .  Request Payload :  {selectedCountryName: "Ireland", GEONAMES_USER: "....", withCredentials: true} GEONAMES_USER: "....."selectedCountryName: "Ireland"withCredentials: true                                                                          
Request Response :{"status":"code":"200","name":"ok","description":"success","returnedIn":"905 ms"},"data":[I took this out but data is good]}

Comment: @ADyson . I am using XAMPP and the PHP server output is taken from htdocs accessed via localhost . http://localhost/eliMullan/project1/backend/src/getWikipedia.php gives No4. PHP server output.                            No.3 is console.log(response.data.data)

Comment: `localhost/eliMullan/project1/backend/src/getWikipedia.php gives No4. PHP server output`...sure, but my question was **where**? And when? You mean on-screen in the page, or in the browser console? Because obviously if you put that URL in your browser and run it, you'll get the problems because, unlike the separate AJAX request, you're not sending any parameters to it that time.